# How do I use the delete key for a macro shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> for a macro shortcut.

How can I do this ?
 
Something about using `Application.OnKey` seems to pop up a lot, but I don't have ANY idea what that means.

Can someone please run me through how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends on what your trying to do really. If you want to just clear the contents of a cell, do this.

```
Sub sbClearCells()
 Range("A1:C10").Clear
End Sub
```

If your wanting to cancel a users double click in a cell, something like

Cancel = true

But

if you REALLY want to do the actual keyboard punch, you'd have to look at sendkeys.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Excel you can assign macro keys to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+any letter.  There ins't built in functionality to assign a macro using any other keys.

You could use the Application.OnKey method to do some pretty cool things. For example, `Application.OnKey "^{DEL}", ""` disables the delete key, but replacing the "" with a different procedure would enable or disable some other functionality. See [this Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx) page for more information.